# Downloaded canvas displays a different font

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a problem on my code where the downloaded image which consist of the canvas and a div on top of it, but when I check the downloaded image the font style of the div is different than what I defined.

Here is the code for the Div

```
<div id="memePlaceHolder" style="height: 700px; width:700px;background:#BBB;">
    <canvas id="c" width="0" height="0">
    </canvas>
    <div id="myTestDiv" name="myTestDiv" >
        <h1>My Test Header</h1>
        <br/>
        <h2>Test Text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="save()">Save as Image</button>
```

Here is the code for the save function

```
function save() {
    html2canvas(wrapperMeme, {
        onrendered: function (canvasMeme) {
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = canvasMeme.toDataURL();
            a.download = 'myImage.png';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the CSS of the div

```
#myTestDiv{
    font-family: 'DIN Condensed Bold';
    color: #F9F3F4;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #000;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    border: solid #F9F3F4 7px;
    float:center;
    width: 40%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @DreiDreiDrei i think you don't have the font in your machine to inherit the font-family.

Comment: @santhosh I have it and already imported it.                                 
    font-face {
     font-family: 'DIN Condensed Bold';
     src:url('/fonts/DIN-Condensed-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original question, it seems like you are using a custom font, as there isn't any default font named **DIN Condensed Bold**.

If that's the case then, you would have to import the font properly in your css using `@font-face` rule.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: DIN Condensed Bold;
  src: url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/justrajdeep/fonts/4b9af53d/DIN%20Condensed%20Bold.ttf);
}
```

---

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
let wrapperMeme = document.querySelector('#memePlaceHolder');

function save() {
    html2canvas(wrapperMeme, {
        onrendered: function (canvasMeme) {
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = canvasMeme.toDataURL();
            a.download = 'myImage.png';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: DIN Condensed Bold;
    src: url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/justrajdeep/fonts/4b9af53d/DIN%20Condensed%20Bold.ttf);
}

#myTestDiv {
    font-family: DIN Condensed Bold;
    color: #F9F3F4;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #000;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    border: solid #F9F3F4 7px;
    float: center;
    width: 40%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="memePlaceHolder" style="height: 700px; width:700px;background:#BBB;">
    <canvas id="c" width="150" height="150">
    </canvas>
    <div id="myTestDiv" name="myTestDiv">
        <h1>My Test Header</h1>
        <br/>
        <h2>Test Text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="save()">Save as Image</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you, I tried importing the font locally earlier.